# Swift: How to convert Array of Dictionary to structure?

Tags: swift

I have:

```
array = [["name": String, "lastName": String],
         ["name": String, "lastName": String], 
         ["name": String, "lastName": String]]  

(a: [Сlass.[String:String]]) -> [Class.SomeStruct] {}
```

How to make a structure with its properties from this array?
Like this:

```
struct SomeStruct {
    let name: String
    let lastName: String
}
```

Comment: Is the dictionary the result of JSON deserialisation? If so, use `Codable` directly and skip the array of dictionaries.

Comment: Look into `map`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `map` or `compactMap` to transform your dictionaries into structs.

```swift
let array = [["name": "String", "lastName": "String"],
["name": "String", "lastName": "String"],
["name": "String", "lastName": "String"]]

struct SomeStruct {
    let name: String
    let lastName: String
}


let values = array.compactMap { data -> SomeStruct? in
    guard let name = data["name"], let lastName = data["lastName"] else {
        return nil
    }
    return SomeStruct(name: name, lastName: lastName)
}
```

Note: The `compactMap` will silently ignore all dictionaries that doesn't contains a `name` or a `lastName` key.

Answer (score 0):

Use Codable

```
// MARK: - SomeStructElement
struct SomeStructElement: Codable, Equatable {
    let name: Int?
    let lastName: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name = "name"
        case lastName = "lastName"
    }
}
```

And then use JSONDecoder:

```
let someStructArray: Array<SomeStructElement> = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Array<SomeStructElement>.self, from: data) ?? []
```

Source: [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types (Apple developer)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

Comment: Why neg my answer ? arguments ?